# iceweasel (firefox) browser re-installation

Tags: software-installation, firefox, kali-linux

I uninstalled my browser (iceweasel) from Add/Remove Software option in Kali Linux.At the time of removal it asked for one dependent package also to be uninstalled that I don't remember.

But now when I am re-installing it as per instruction given on its official Site , it's giving the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package iceweasel is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only    available  from another source
E: Package 'iceweasel' has no installation candidate
```

Any suggestions !!!

Comment: Could you give the name of the site you are mentioning?

Comment: http://www.geticeweasel.org/

Comment: could you give the output of `apt-cache search iceweasel --names-only`

Comment: Its giving no result.Their is some problem with my source.list.Many people suggested me that.But I dont know anything about it

Comment: What is tthe content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Comment: deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot i386 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20130327-18:35]/ kali contrib main non-free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following lines into your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://http.kali.org/ /kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/ /wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

and then run

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install iceweasel
```

Comment: I am a newbie .Can you please give me command od adding this and from where you got this stuff

Comment: http://kali4hackers.blogspot.de/2013/05/add-repository-kali-linux.html

Comment: You can use nano to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: yes I got leafpad.Its upgrading right now I will inform you final result :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Raphael.It took 2 hrs to upgrade all for just 13 Mb software.But learned something new.Thanks buddy